# Jenkins: how can I clean temp folders after a new job is triggered?

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, maven-surefire-plugin

I have multiple projects configured in Jenkins (Maven projects) for an automation framework (UI) which uses multiple browser sessions (Chrome). When a build finished I can see that no cleanup is done and around 5GB of garbage left by Chrome are still stored in C:\Users\svc.localjkn\AppData\Local\Temp.
I have tried using : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Tmp+Cleaner+Plugin but this does not actually work ?
If anybody encountered the same situation and find a viable solution can you please share this with me ?

Many thanks,
Aila

Answer (score 0):

with the little info I have all I can do is suggest to remove the temp folder yourself by executing a command line script at the end of your job

something like

```
rd /s /q C:\Users\svc.localjkn\AppData\Local\Temp\myTempFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with below step.

1. Run jenkins with bat command and add option
   **"-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Jenkins\remoting "**

Example:
java -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Jenkins\remoting -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://1.2.34.5:8080/computer/winNode/slave-agent.jnlp -secret xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -workDir "C:\Jenkins"

This will create jenkins job bat file on path C:Jenkins/Remoting instead of temp folder

2. Then in you job use windows dir cleanup command.
   **rd %temp% /s /q**

For bat files jenkins complete a auto cleanup.